# Creating mock object for database dependency in JUnit testing

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I have created a JUnit test that uses a database connectivity in order to fetch some data and then compares the result with some value to validate.
I know I can use a `Mock Object` concept to remove the database dependency of a test function but I don't know how to do it.

**This is my test class method-**

ValidateTest.java

```
public void testValidateID() {
    Validate validateFields = new Validate();   
    MyID userID = readXmlAndReturnID("UserID.xml");
    boolean expectedResponse = true;
    boolean actualResponse = validateFields.validateSpecifiedID(myID);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
}
```

**This is my actual class method that uses database -**

Validate.java

```
public boolean validateSpecifiedID(MyID myID){
List<String> incomingList = myID.getuserID();
UserIDProgramHome userIDProgramHome = new UserIDProgramHome();

//this requires postgres database connectivity
idList = userIDProgramHome.findIDsByProgram(myID); 
    if(idList.get(0).equals(incomingList.get(0))){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I know I can use a Mock Object concept [...] but I don't know how to do it." Then you first should work through some tutorials about it. After studying that somewhat complex field, you will find out that your class is tightly coupled to your other class `UserIDProgramHome`. These dependencies make mocking very difficult. At the end you will have to redesign you application.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of injecting your mock object into your class under test. The problem with your `validateSpecifiedID()` method is that it creates an instance of `UserIDProgramHome` within the method itself, when it appears this is probably the object you need to mock.

A common solution is to refactor your code so that these sorts of dependencies are passed to the constructor of the class. Then in your test, you can passed a mocked object instead and verify the behaviour of the class under test.

Looking at your particular test, I would consider mocking two things: your `MyID` instance and the `UserIDProgramHome` you pass to your new `Validate` constructor. The only thing you care about in your test is that the method inspects the results of `myID.getuserID()` and, depending upon the result of `userIDProgramHome.findIDsByProgram()`, returns true or false.

Comment: Can I also do the other approach to pass the `idList` object as an argument to the `validateSpecifiedID` method instead of using it in the method itself. Doing so will free the method from database related stuff. This way I can simply call this method in my test class without issues.

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution will depend on the mocking library/libraries you use for the test. Using JMockit, you could write the test as follows, leaving the code under test as is:

```
@Test
public void testValidateID(@Mocked final UserIDProgramHome home) {
    Validate validateFields = new Validate();   
    MyID userID = readXmlAndReturnID("UserID.xml");
    final String firstIDValue = userID.getUserID().get(0);

    new Expectations() {{
        home.findIDsByProgram((MyID) any); result = firstIDValue;
    }};

    boolean idIsValid = validateFields.validateSpecifiedID(userID);

    assertTrue(idIsValid);
}
```

An equivalent test can also be written with Mockito + PowerMock. In either case, no modifications need to be made to class `Validate`.